# Set domain for cookie, res.cookie() didn't work in NodeJs

Tags: node.js

For example :

**in apiController.js domain didn't set for cookie:**

**server.js file**

```
var express = require('express'),
  app = express(),
  port = 3000,
  routes = require('./app/routes/apiRoutes');

app.use(routes)

app.listen(port);
```

**routes.js file**

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function( app ) {

    var api= require('../controllers/apiController');

    app.route('/get').get(api.get);

};
```

***apiController.js file***

```
 'use strict';

 exports.get = function(req, res) {

    res.cookie( 'name', 'value', {domain: '.example.com'} ).send();

 };
```

Comment: How are you checking that the cookie isn't being set?

Comment: @robertklep send request with postman and I checked from there, cookie will be set but domain not.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code, though.